# Replace rotted plywood sheathing behind stucco

Tags: chimney, stucco, sheathing, dry-rot

I have a chimney chase where water was leaking down the side for years.  I had the fireplace and flue removed. In the chase, the plywood sheathing has all rotted away from the stucco.  I can remove the other rotted wood and will replace some framing.

But how do I reattach the sheathing to the inside of the stucco?

Not knowing anything, I was planning on using nail nippers to remove existing screws sticking through, attach the new plywood sheathing with construction adhesive, add some framing for support, and add some screws from the outside through the stucco to the new sheathing.

[image]

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm far from expert in this field. You probably could replace the sheathing from the inside as you're planning on doing, but I would think that it's likely that the stucco will fail much sooner. I believe that those screws you're planning on nipping off are to help hold the stucco/mesh to the plywood to help provide physical support for it. Without that additional support, I would think the stucco will start to fail sooner meaning that you're going to be replacing the stucco in a few years. My 2 cents worth...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the correct way to fix this is "rip off the stucco, replace the rotten wood, apply new stucco."

Comment: Plus fix whatever was leaking.

Comment: Absolutely correct. The tar paper is what separates the stucco from the plywood, is CRITICAL that it go back in place. Stucco will let a percentage of the water pass through, so it is a essential part of the system, besides the nails/screws that hold it to the wall. Also if any water gets past the other measures in place to keep it out. It is the last defense for major water infiltration.